# mod_security prevents Apache from starting - no errors

Tags: apache, security, mod-security

I installed mod_security 2.8.0 on my Apache 2.4 installation. I copied the yajl.dll into my bin folder, the .so file into my modules, added the configuration as the readme suggested, but when I start Apache, it fails.

But it only fails if I specify rules (I tried a lot of different ones, one at a time). Every time there is a rule, Apache fails to start.

If I go with only

```
SecRuleEngine On
SecDefaultAction "deny,phase:2,status:403"
```

Then it works fine. The error log shows only:

```
[Mon May 19 11:24:10.010299 2014] [:notice] [pid 2820:tid 496] ModSecurity for Apache/2.8.0 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Mon May 19 11:24:10.010299 2014] [:notice] [pid 2820:tid 496] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.5.0"; loaded version="1.5.0"
[Mon May 19 11:24:10.010299 2014] [:notice] [pid 2820:tid 496] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.34 "; loaded version="8.34 2013-12-15"
[Mon May 19 11:24:10.010299 2014] [:notice] [pid 2820:tid 496] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Mon May 19 11:24:10.010299 2014] [:notice] [pid 2820:tid 496] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.1"
```

I.e. no errors. If I add a rule that is misconfigured (missing ID) it will log it here, but as you can see it doesn't - but Apache won't start.

System is Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I had this problem just minutes ago, and diagnosed that the mod_security installation changed my server root in the httpd_conf to "c:/apache24/" when there was no such file on my system, I changed it back to "c:/xampp/apache/" and it started up just fine again, no probs.